# AnguarJS - bootstapping an application means?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In AngularJS documetation, it tells that, "The ng-app directive starts an AngularJS Application. It defines the root element. It automatically initializes or bootstraps the application when the web page containing AngularJS Application is loaded."

What does bootstrapping the application mean? does it mean it automatically makes the application responsive?

Just had another question - difference between bootstrap and twitter-bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

tiwtter-bootstrap is a UX library http://getbootstrap.com/components/

When AngularJS bootstraps your app.  It initializes your app by parsing your dependencies, creating services, and ultimately binding your JS Controllers to the HTML DOM.

Answer (score 0):

*Bootstrapping* means *starting it*.

You can either start it automatically with the *ngApp* directive or manually calling `angular.bootstrap(element, ['name of your main app module'])`, where `element` is the root DOM/HTML element for your Angular app (for example, `element` would be retrieved this way: `angular.element(document.getElementById("myApp"))`).

Usually manual boostrapping occurs in applications that load files asynchronously and need to wait until all modules are actually loaded into the browser. Once every file has been already loaded, you manually *start*/*bootstrap* the Angular app.

Comment: So in other words, it does not make your app responsive automatically.

Comment: @gopalrao No, hahaha ;) It's Twitter who introduced *bootstrap* word as other thing than "initializing an app"...